# How to make md-toolbar "fixed on top" using angular/flex-layout?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to make angular2-material2 toolbar stay on the top and sidenav container scrollable with https://github.com/angular/flex-layout.

```
<div fxLayout='column'>
    <md-toolbar #toolbar color="primary">
    ....
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-sidenav-container class="my-container">
    ....
    </md-sidenav-container>
</div>
....
.my-container md-sidenav {
  max-width: 200px;
}

.my-container .md-sidenav-content,
.my-container md-sidenav {
  display: flex;
}
```

I saw some examples how to do this with angularJS-material using `flex="none"`, but i can't find example for angular/flex-layout.